# SKPhysicsBody objects collisions are not aligned

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a player. He has to jump over some blocks.

However, it seems like the `SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ... )` isn't aligned properly. When the character hits the upper half of the block it just passes through and he can't pass below it because it collides with an invisible `SKPhysicsBody`.

Depending on how I put the anchor point it sometimes even happens that the physics body is to the left or right of it's `SKSpriteNode`.

My code for the blocks:

```
    self.smallBlock.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.smallBlock.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + self.smallBlock.size.width, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + self.runningBar.size.height * 2)

    self.smallBlock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.smallBlock.size)
    self.smallBlock.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.smallBlock.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colliderType.Block.rawValue
    self.smallBlock.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colliderType.Character.rawValue
    self.smallBlock.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colliderType.Character.rawValue
    self.smallBlock.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    self.addChild(self.smallBlock)

    self.character.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.25)
    self.character.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - self.character.size.width, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + self.character.size.height)
    self.initPosX = CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + (self.character.size.width * 1.25)
```

Code for the character

```
    self.character.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.25)
    self.character.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - self.character.size.width, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + self.character.size.height)
    self.initPosX = CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + (self.character.size.width * 1.25)

    self.character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.character.size)
    self.character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.character.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colliderType.Character.rawValue
    self.character.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colliderType.Block.rawValue
    self.character.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colliderType.Block.rawValue
    self.character.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    self.character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.character.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    self.addChild(self.character)
```

Comment: Could be the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045203/physicsbody-doesnt-adhere-to-nodes-anchor-point

Comment: It is, but that one is not in Swift. I've tried to edit it for swift but it doesn't work because Swift doesn't have `pathForRectangleOfSize:withAnchorPoint`.

Comment: That's because @bshirley added that class method too - you need to also translate `pathForRectangleOfSize:withAnchorPoint`.

Comment: That might be Swift's rectangleOfSize:Center:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I've added `skView.showsPhysics = true` to my View Controller. When you run the app in the simulator it will outline every object like shown [here](http://oi62.tinypic.com/rjqce0.jpg).

It turns out setting custom anchor points messes up the `rectangleOfSize`-positions.